# PHP empty not working?

Tags: php

The site that I am working on is throwing an exception with "Integrity constraint violation: Column 'ip' cannot be null"

This only happens one to 5 times daily (while the site gets 100's of hits daily)- but I don't understand how it is even possible.

My code is as follows:

```
$ip = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getClientIp();
if(empty($ip))
return;
```

Then write to the database.

If IP is null, how can it get passed the empty check?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to set as 'NULL' in your database ip field.. so your problem will be resolved..

Comment: `var_dump($ip)` check what r u getting, will resolved your confusion.

Comment: Take a look at the bigger scope, _where_ does return jump to? What happens then?

Comment: When you say set as 'Null' you mean to allow Null values - right? I know I can do that, but it really should not be null. Also I can't do var_dump($ip) as I can't reproduce the problem. It is happening randomly. And it terms of return - shouldn't it end the function and thus skip the insert to db?

Comment: try if(!$ip) maybe will work. for more info, go to : [PHP type comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is:

```
if($ip=== NULL) {...}
```

PHP treats NULL, false, 0, and the empty string as equal.